# Given that $f'(x)g(x) = g'(x)f(x)$ show that g has a root

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing

I'm given a question which reads:

"suppose $f(x)g'(x) = f'(x)g(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. Let $r_{1}, r_{2} \in (a,b)$ where $r_{1} < r_{2}$ be two consecutive roots of $f$. Also, $f(x) \ne 0$ for any $x \in (r1, r2)$. Furthermore assume that $g(r_{1}) \ne 0$ and $g(r_{2}) \ne 0$. Show that g must have a root in $(r_{1}, r_{2})$.

My attempt:

We know that $f(r_{1}) = f(r_{2}) = 0$. So $0 = g(r_{1})f'(r_{1})$. Since $g(r_{1}) \ne 0$, it follows that $f'(r_{1}) = 0$. A similar argument can be made for $r_{2}$. Now, since $f(r_{1}) = 0$ and $f(r_{2}) = 0$, then there must be a $x_{1} \in(r_{1}, r_{2})$ such that $f'(x_{1}) = 0$. So, $f(x_{1})g'(x_{1}) = g(x_{1})f'(x_{1}) \to f(x_{1})g'(x_{1}) = 0 \to g'(x_{1}) = 0$, which means that g has an extremeum at that point.

That's about as far as I can get before getting stuck.

Answer (score 6):

My thoughts so far:
$$f(x)g'(x) = f'(x)g(x)$$
$$0 = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$$
$$f(x) = cg(x)$$

Comment: emm I believe last equation should be $f(x)=cg(x)$ and this solves the problem.

Comment: Right, edited. Thank you! Why does this solve the problem though?

Comment: @Kaynex Sorry, but where does the $g(x)^2$ come from?

Comment: There is the assumption that $g(r_1) \neq 0$ but $f(r_1)=0$

Comment: Divided by g(x)² arbitrarily to show off the quotient rule application.

Comment: @Kaynex Ah ok. However, I just don't see how this shows g has a root in (r1, r2). We know f(r1) = 0 and $g(r_{1}) \ne 0$. So how does this show that  $g$ has a root in $(r_{1}, r_{2})$?

Comment: The argument goes along the lines: Assume g has no roots....

Comment: I think it's better to go the other way, ie show that $\frac d{dx} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=0$, since we know $f\neq0$ on $(r_1,r_2)$. In any case, this appears to show that the assumptions of the question are impossible to satisfy.

Comment: @Manny Agreed, this is not a final answer but just some thoughts. As far as I can tell, the assumption must be wrong. Any root in f must also be a root in g. This may not be the intended method of solution.

Comment: If $f(x)=cg(x)$ then $f(x)g'(x)=cg(x)g'(x)=cg'(x)g(x)=f'(x)g(x)$  great! But we know that there is a $x$ such that $f(x)\ne0$ and from this I get that $c\ne0$ so: $f(r_1)=cg(r_1)=0\implies g(r_1)=\frac0c=0$

Comment: @Holo 8 But the question states that $g(r_{1}) \ne 0$. So is the question wong then?

Comment: @Manny I don't think so, I posted my thoughts as an answer, look at it

Answer (score 0):

Following Kaynes very good idea: *suppose* $\;g\;$ doesn't vanish in $\;(a,b)\;$ , then we can write for all $\;x\in (a,b)\;$ :

$$f'(x)g(x)=g'(x)f(x)\implies\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)'=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}=0\implies f(x)=cg(x)$$

for some constant $\;c\in\Bbb R\;$ . But this then means $\;g(r_i)=cf(r_i)=0\;$, contradiction...

Comment: So the question is wrong?

Comment: @Manny No. Why do you think it is?

Comment: because it states that $g(r_{1}) \ne 0$ and $f(r_{1}) = 0$. Here, you showed that f(x) = cg(x) which means that f(r1) = cg(r1) -> 0 = cg(r1). So either c = 0 or g(r1) = 0 right?

Comment: @Manny No. What I showed is that *under the assumption that* $\;g\;$ doesn't vanish in $\;(a,b)\;$. we arrive to the contradiction $\;g(r_1)=g(r_2)=0\;$. which means our assumption is wrong, meaning: $\;g\;$ **must vanish** at some point $\;x_0\in (a,b)\;$ . Q.E.D.

Comment: But how do we know that the point where it vanishes $x \in (a,b)$ is in $(r_{1}, r_{2})$?

Comment: @Manny, we **assume** (reductio ad absurdum) that there is **no** point $\;x\in (a,b)\;$ , or if you prefer $\;x\in (r_1,r_2)\;$ s.t. $\;g(x)=0\;$ . Because of this assumption we can apply the formula of differential of a ratio $\;f/g\;$ and get $\;\left(f/g\right)'=\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}\;$ , which we **cannot use** unless we know $\;g\neq0\;$ in the whole open interval. From here we got a contradiction as shown, meaning: it **must be that** $\;g(x)=0\;$ for some $\;x\in (r_1,r_2)\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

I will take what @Kaynex showed: $f(x)=cg(x)$

Now we know that for some $x$ we have $f(x)\ne0\ne cg(x)\implies c\ne0$

Hence:$$f(r_1)=0=cg(r_1)\implies g(r_1)=\frac0c=0$$ this is contradiction to the assumption, thus a step in @Kaynex way is illegal, the only step it can be is: $$0=f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)\rightarrow 0=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}$$

Which implies that for some $x$, say $x_0$, we have $g^2(x_0)=0$ hence $g(x_0)=0$

Comment: I understand that saying we have contradiction makes you think that the question is wrong but what it really do is showing that we did an "illegal" move, in this case we divided by $0$, which means that $g(x)$ has to be equal to $0$ at some point, if it is still not clear say and I'll explain further how it works in this case

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. It does follow the same principles though:

Assume $g$ has no zeros in $(r_1, r_2)$. Then we can manipulate the condition $fg'=f'g$ to get:

$$\frac {f'} f = \frac {g'}g\\
\frac {d}{dx} \log(f) = \frac {d}{dx} \log (g)\\
\log f=\log g+c$$
Thus $f=\tilde c g, \text{ where } \tilde c=e^c \neq 0$.

But then $0=f(r_1)=\tilde c g(r_1) \neq 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Holo Oh, that soudve been logs in that line